# Update live activity with local notification

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, widgetliveactivity

I know we can update live activities using remote push notifications with APNs.

But is it also possible to update a live activity using a local notification?

Comment: Shouldn't the notification be received by your app, you treat it, and then update if needed the Live Activity?

Comment: The idea behind live activities is to provide real-time or near-real-time updates. Why would you update a live activity using local notification?

Comment: @Larme yes, but I want to update it without having the user to touch the notification and therefore open the app. I want to update it in the background.

Comment: @PierreJanineh cause I want to update a countdown timer after its value hits 0

Comment: Please be specific on what have you tried, what research have you done, and what didn't work for you so we could help. READ THIS: [How do I ask a good question on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use silent push. You din’t have to show to the user a notification